# excel macro/vba if/then with looping thru multiple sheets looking for specific text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a macro that opens an excel workbook, goes to the first tab, looks in cell a1 for certain text, if it matches, then it copies a section of that worksheet and pastes in another workbook, then it goes to the next worksheet.  If it does not match, it goes to the next worksheet and completes the above.  Then so forth.

I have written the macro, but it is not working.  I am having issues with the moving to the next worksheet.

```
Sub CopyTierSummarySpecific()
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    folderPath = "C:\2019\03 Mar" 'contains folder path
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")
Do While Filename <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)

        Sheets("Data").Select   'This is the first worksheet in all workbooks


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


    If Range("A1").Value = "Include" Then
        Range("E16:AV" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Test FPS.xlsm").Activate

        Worksheets("Summary").Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Else



    End If

 Next ws
```

Comment: I added the code that I created.

Answer (score 0):

**Not Tested**

1. You build strings with the `&` operator, not the `+` operator. Your statement of `folderpath = folderpath + "\"` will fail. If your code made it past this error it means one of two things (**A:** you have `On Error` which is not a good trap for this case or **B:** you have not tested this code against a folderpath that doesn't already end with '\'
2. Qualify your objects. Every worksheet object should be qualified with that worksheet. Else you may end up with some unexpected outputs, especially since you were using `.Select`
3. Remove `.Select`. No need to rely on what's selected when you can explicitly state where your code should operate
4. Declaring variables to store your last rows will make for cleaner code that is easier to read. (`cLR & pLR`)

---

```
Sub CopyTier()

Dim fn As String, path As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim cLR As Long, pLR As Long
Dim Book As Workbook: Set Book = Windows("Test FPS.xlsm")

path = "C:\2019\03 Mar"
fn = Dir(path & "*.xls*")

Do While fn <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fn)

        If ws.Range("A1") = "Include" Then
            cLR = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            pLR = Book.Range("B" & Book.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

            ws.Range("E16:AV" & cLR).Copy
            Book.Range("B" & pLR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Loop

End Sub
```